# MassTransit Saga State to Instance State Mapping

Tags: c#, masstransit, automatonymous

I'm new to MassTransit, and I can't seem to figure out how it maps the States that I define on a saga (MassTransitStateMachine) to the "State" property on the related SagaStateMachineInstance class.

For example, if I have a state machine class with three states:

```
public class MySaga :
   MassTransitStateMachine<MySagaState>
{
    public State Executing { get; private set; }
    public State Completed { get; private set; }
    public State Failed { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

And my state machine instance class has a "State" property

```
public class MySagaState : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

How does MT decide which saga state is which integer?

There also appear to be two built-in saga states, "Initial" and "Final", so this example would have 5 states. How is the State to integer mapping done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `State` property indicates the current state machine state. It changes whenever the state machine gets to another state.

It can either be of a complex type `State` or primitive type `string` or `int`. The first case, if you use database persistence, the `Name` property of the `State` object will be stored in the database. If you use `string` (all MassTransit examples suggest this) - it is obvious that the property will contain the state name, representing the state machine property name. If you use `int` - it is the hardest to understand by looking at the value, since it has come convention like zero is no state, one is the initial state, 2 is the final state and 3 onwards represent all other states.

I would really suggest using `string`, since it is easier to map and there is no confusion.

So your saga state will look like:

```
public class MySagaState : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
}
```

you should also configure the state property of the state machine state object in the state machine constructor:

```
InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);
```

Along the execution of this saga, this property will get values `Executing`, `Completed` or `Failed` as you have defined the state properties.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the states in order to assign numbers to them as part of the state machine definition:

```
public class MySaga :
  MassTransitStateMachine<MySagaState>
{
    public MySaga()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.State, Executing, Completed, Failed);
        // 1 = Initial, 2 = Final, 3 = Executing, 4 = Completed
        // 5 - Failed (1 & 2 are built-in states)
    }

    public State Executing { get; private set; }
    public State Completed { get; private set; }
    public State Failed { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```